# What is null when importing the XML?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to import data from an xml file and sort them in order, but when i run it, i get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." here is a snippet of the code im using.

```
XElement data = XElement.Load("blockData.xml");

var sortedElements = 
from c in data.Element("BLOCKS").Elements("BLOCK")
orderby (string)c.Element("X") descending,
        (string)c.Element("Y") descending,
        (string)c.Element("Z") descending
        select new
        {
            name1 = (string)c.Element("NAME"),
            X1 = (string)c.Element("X"),
            Y1 = (string)c.Element("Y"),
            Z1 = (string)c.Element("Z")
        };
 foreach (var r in sortedElements)
 Console.WriteLine("X:{0} Y:{1} Z:{2} Name:{3}",
          r.X1, r.Y1, r.Z1, r.name1);
```

And a sample of what is contained in the XML file

```
<BLOCKS>
  <BLOCK>
   <NAME>B1</NAME>
   <X>0</X>
   <Y>0</Y>
   <Z>0</Z>
  </BLOCK>
</BLOCKS>
```

Comment: I am not a LINQ pro, but have you tried Descendants instead of Elements?

Comment: On which row is the exception thrown? If it is within your foreach-loop, you can simply check if(r != null){console.writeln...}

Comment: I tried descendants aswell but it didnt work, still same error.
It appears that var sortedElements is throwing the nullreference exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
var sortedElements = 
from c in data.Root.Elements("BLOCK")
```

Because BLOCKS is the root of the XML.

Comment: XElement does not have a Root. Only XDocument does.

Comment: I think the downvote's a little harsh - the answer is correct.  BLOCKS is the current element; a simple misnomer.

Comment: We don't know what the top element is. That information is missing from the question.

Answer (score -1):

After taking on board what some of you have sugested and reserach on other problems like this, I found out that you need to explicitly access the value of the node as shown below to overcome the problem of the nullreference exception

```
var sortedElements =
    from c in data.DescendantsAndSelf("BLOCKS").Elements("BLOCK")
    orderby 
         c.Element("X").Value descending,
         c.Element("Y").Value descending,
         c.Element("Z").Value descending
    select new
    {
        name1 = (string)c.Element("NAME"),
        X1 = (string)c.Element("X"),
        Y1 = (string)c.Element("Y"),
        Z1 = (string)c.Element("Z")
    };
    foreach (var r in sortedElements)
    Console.WriteLine("X:{0} Y:{1} Z:{2} Name:{3}",
           r.X1, r.Y1, r.Z1, r.name1);
```

aswell as adding root elements to the XML file

```
<root>

    <BLOCKS> . . . </BLOCKS>

</root>
```

Comment: So... what was the actual problem?

Comment: when pointing at c.Element("X") descending for example, it turns out that it wasn't pointing at the values inside the element just at the location of the element, that's what i found online anyway.